# Spreading sequence for dsss or cdma

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

In spread spectrum systems like DSSS or CDMA, we can take a pseudo-random sequence composed of 1 and -1. But can we use a complex number sequence between -1 and 1? Why is this type of sequence never used?
Here are the Matlab codes:

```
pn=2*(rand(1,128)>0.5)-1; %pn code
comp=(2*(rand(1,128)>0.5)-1)+1i*(2*(rand(1,128)>0.5)-1); %complex code
```

Comment: Look into Zadoff-Chu sequences for example of complex spreading codes: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zadoff%E2%80%93Chu_sequence.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this type of sequence never used?

Complex spreading sequences are used all over the place: OFDMA is a special case of CDMA, for example.